# How to access the filepath of an image from a view on a content type

Tags: media, files

I have a problem Accessing the file path of an uploaded image. I'm trying to create a custom Carousel and build it up in a Drupal Block. I'm pulling the array created from the view of the content type like so:

```
$slides = views_get_view_result('slide');

foreach ($slides as $slide) {
    echo $slide->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_slide_image['und'][0]['uri'];
}
```

My problem is that URI prints out "public://someimage.jpg" instead of "someimage.jpg" or "sites/all/images/someimage.jpg." I know I could do a string replace on this, but Drupal must have a way of getting the right file path to the image. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`file_create_url($uri)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) which will generate an absolute URL (including [`$base_url`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--globals.php/global/base_url/7) which contains your server domain name).

`print file_create_url('public://someimage.jpg');` will generate something like `http://localhost/sites/default/files/someimage.jpg` if your website is installed in localhost and your files are located in the default directory.